# setting Brightness Contrast Hue Saturation for a specific element with FLEX

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm trying to allow the user to set the Brightness, Contrast, Hue, and Saturation for the remote users Camera (this will just affect the local user that is adjusting the preferences) with a Slider. I don't see a class for this here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html# so I used the libraries below to set the element "remoteVideo" (the remote camera) to whatever the user desires for Brightness, Contrast, Hue, and Saturation. I'm getting a syntax error for                  color.brightness.remoteVideo(0, BrightnessSlider.value); (and for Contrast, Hue, and Saturation) that says (Multiple Markers at this Line. 1119: Access of Undefined property brightess through a reference with fl.motion.adjustcolor & -  Access of undefined property remoteVideo, which is clearly defined since the RTMFP Video Chat works\compiles fine without the code below:

( Original Sourcecode without my changes below if it helps: https://github.com/MonaSolutions/MonaClients/blob/master/VideoPhone/src/VideoPhone.mxml )

// Libraries for Brightness Contrast Hue Saturation

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import fl.motion.AdjustColor;
import flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;   
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
```

// variables for Brightness Contrast Hue Saturation

```
        private var color:AdjustColor = new AdjustColor(); //This object will hold the color properties
        private var filter:ColorMatrixFilter; //Will store the modified color filter to change the video
```

// **FIXED** functions

```
        private function BrightnessLevel(e:Event = null):void
        {
            color.brightness = BrightnessSlider.value;
            var mMatrix:Array = color.CalculateFinalFlatArray();
            filter = new ColorMatrixFilter(mMatrix);
            remoteVideo.filters = [filter];
            status("Setting brightness to: " + BrightnessSlider.value + "\n");
        }

        private function ContrastLevel(e:Event = null):void
        {

            color.contrast = ContrastSlider.value;
            var mMatrix:Array = color.CalculateFinalFlatArray();
            filter = new ColorMatrixFilter(mMatrix);
            remoteVideo.filters = [filter];
            status("Setting contrast to: " + ContrastSlider.value + "\n");

        }

        private function HueLevel(e:Event = null):void
        {


            color.hue = HueSlider.value;
            var mMatrix:Array = color.CalculateFinalFlatArray();
            filter = new ColorMatrixFilter(mMatrix);
            remoteVideo.filters = [filter];
            status("Setting hue to: " + HueSlider.value + "\n");

        }

        private function SaturationLevel(e:Event = null):void
        {


            color.saturation = SaturationSlider.value;
            var mMatrix:Array = color.CalculateFinalFlatArray();
            filter = new ColorMatrixFilter(mMatrix);
            remoteVideo.filters = [filter];
            status("Setting saturation to: " + SaturationSlider.value + "\n");

        }
```

// sliders for Brightness Contrast Hue Saturation

```
        <s:NavigatorContent label="ADJUST COLORS" enabled="{currentState != LoginNotConnected}">
            <s:layout>
                <s:HorizontalLayout/>
            </s:layout>

            <s:VGroup>
                <s:HGroup>
                    <s:Panel width="247" height="67.5" backgroundColor="0xA0A0A0"
                             title="Brightness">
                        <s:layout>
                            <s:VerticalLayout paddingLeft="8"/>
                        </s:layout>
                        <s:HSlider id="BrightnessSlider" width="220"
                                   change="BrightnessLevel(event)" maximum="100" minimum="-100"
                                   showDataTip="false" value="0"/>
                    </s:Panel>

                    <s:Panel width="247" height="67.5" backgroundColor="0xA0A0A0"
                             title="Contrast">
                        <s:layout>
                            <s:VerticalLayout paddingLeft="8"/>
                        </s:layout>
                        <s:HSlider id="ContrastSlider" width="220" change="ContrastLevel(event)"
                                   maximum="100" minimum="-100" showDataTip="false" value="0"/>
                    </s:Panel>
                </s:HGroup>

                <s:HGroup>

                    <s:Panel width="247" height="67.5" backgroundColor="0xA0A0A0" title="Hue">
                        <s:layout>
                            <s:VerticalLayout paddingLeft="8"/>
                        </s:layout>
                        <s:HSlider id="HueSlider" width="220" change="HueLevel(event)"
                                   maximum="180" minimum="-180" showDataTip="false" value="0"/>
                    </s:Panel>
                    <s:Panel width="247" height="67.5" backgroundColor="0xA0A0A0"
                             title="Saturation">
                        <s:layout>
                            <s:VerticalLayout paddingLeft="8"/>
                        </s:layout>
                        <s:HSlider id="SaturationSlider" width="220"
                                   change="SaturationLevel(event)" maximum="100" minimum="-100"
                                   showDataTip="false" value="0"/>
                    </s:Panel>
                </s:HGroup>
            </s:VGroup>




        </s:NavigatorContent>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the documentation for AdjustColor, each of those properties (brightness, contrast, hue, saturation) is a Number. So this line:

```
color.brightness.remoteVideo(0, BrightnessSlider.value);
```

is trying to access the property `remoteVideo` from `color.brightness` which is a Number. It's telling you that there is no property "remoteVideo" on Number.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/motion/AdjustColor.html

Edit:
Something like this may or may not work: (I haven't tested this)

```
color.brightness = BrightnessSlider.value;
var mMatrix:Array = color.CalculateFinalFlatArray();
filter = new ColorMatrixFilter(mMatrix);
remoteVideo.filters = [filter];
```

---

You can avoid creating a new Filter constantly by instantiating it once and just updating its matrix property.

```
    private var color:AdjustColor = new AdjustColor(); //This object will hold the color properties
    private var filter:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter(); //Will store the modified color filter to change the video

    private function BrightnessLevel(e:Event = null):void
    {
        status("Setting brightness to: " + BrightnessSlider.value + "\n");
        color.brightness = BrightnessSlider.value;
        applyFilter();
    }

    private function ContrastLevel(e:Event = null):void
    {
        status("Setting contrast to: " + ContrastSlider.value + "\n");
        color.contrast = ContrastSlider.value;
        applyFilter();
    }

    private function HueLevel(e:Event = null):void
    {
        status("Setting hue to: " + HueSlider.value + "\n");
        color.hue = HueSlider.value;
        applyFilter();
    }

    private function SaturationLevel(e:Event = null):void
    {
        status("Setting saturation to: " + SaturationSlider.value + "\n");
        color.saturation = SaturationSlider.value;
        applyFilter();
    }

    private function applyFilter():void
    {
        filter.matrix = color.CalculateFinalFlatArray();
        remoteVideo.filters = [filter];
    }
```

Comment: I'll test it and comment further + upvote it if it works. Thanks for taking the time to hear me out.

Comment: You were so helpful. Thank you! Thank you thank you!

Comment: Hey again. I'm having an odd issue. So on one computer... until I change the Brightness slider for the first time, the other Sliders values aren't reflected in the Camera.. and on another computer until I change the Saturation for the first time, the changes aren't updated as I move the other sliders... Any idea?

Comment: I updated my functions above if you want to take a look.

Comment: @michelle That is strange. Not sure about that one. But maybe it has to do with the fact that you're creating new Filters constantly as you slide. I made an edit above to simplify everything. Can you try that?

Comment: I'm still having the same issue after your changes. This is very odd. Here is the original source: https://github.com/MonaSolutions/MonaClients/blob/master/VideoPhone/src/VideoPhone.mxml

Comment: Are the status messages updating correctly as you slide?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89106/discussion-between-karmacon-and-michelle).

Comment: Setting saturation to: -41
Setting saturation to: -64
Setting saturation to: -67
Setting contrast to: 45
Setting contrast to: 19
Setting contrast to: -22
Setting contrast to: -39
Setting contrast to: -40
Setting brightness to: -77
Setting brightness to: -61
Setting brightness to: -35
Setting brightness to: -15
Setting brightness to: -5
Setting brightness to: 13
Setting brightness to: 15
Setting hue to: 172
Setting hue to: 169
Setting hue to: 166
Setting hue to: 163
Setting hue to: 160
Setting hue to: 157
Setting hue to: 154
Setting hue to: 151

Comment: Do you think it could be the range \ default value I have set?

Comment: hey im still having issues from yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469093/button-is-not-functioning-properly-resetting-adjustcolors any chance you could help one last time?